# Angular 2: How to use template reference variables in the new forms from RC2 to display error messages?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I just migrated to the new forms for Angular 2 rc 2 and am having trouble using template reference variables to check if an input field has been touched. The form itself and the validators work.

This is how I did it before the changes introduced with rc 2:

```html
<form [ngFormModel]="adminForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input [ngFormControl]="adminForm.controls['email']" [(ngModel)]="admin.email"  #email="ngForm"
  type="text" class="form-control" id="admin_email">
  <div *ngIf="adminForm.hasError('required', 'email') && email.touched" class="alert alert-danger">Email is required</div>
  <div *ngIf="adminForm.hasError('pattern', 'email') && email.touched" class="alert alert-danger">Not a valid email address</div>
</form>
```

My new Component, adapted for the brand new rc 2 forms looks like this:

```
// login.component.ts
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { Admin } from '../shared/models/admin.model';

@Component ({
  selector: 'fac-login',
  moduleId: module.id,
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})
export class LoginComponent {

  public loginForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;

  constructor(
    public admin: Admin
  ) {
    var email_regex = '[a-z0-9\\.\\-\\_]+@[a-z0-9\\.\\-\\_]+\\.[a-z0-9\\.\\-\\_]+';
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(email_regex)]),
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    // handle submit
  }

}
```

---

```
// login.component.html
```

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="loginForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
        formControlName="email" [(ngModel)]="admin.email" #email="ngModel">
    <div *ngIf="loginForm.hasError('required', 'email') && email.touched" class="alert alert-danger">Email is required</div>
    <div *ngIf="loginForm.hasError('pattern', 'email') && email.touched" class="alert alert-danger">Not a valid email address</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control"
      formControlName="password" [(ngModel)]="admin.password" #password="ngModel">
    <div *ngIf="loginForm.hasError('required', 'password') && password.touched" class="alert alert-danger">Password is required</div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" (" type="text" class="form-control"
 formControlName="email" [(ngModel)]="admin.email" [ERROR ->]#email="ngModel">
 <div *ngIf="loginForm.hasError('required', 'email') && email.touched" c"): LoginComponent@12:66
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("assword" class="form-control"
 formControlName="password" [(ngModel)]="admin.password" [ERROR ->]#password="ngModel">
 <div *ngIf="loginForm.hasError('required', 'password') && password.t"): LoginComponent@19:70
```

So the linking of the template reference variable to the form directive doesn't work but I also don't know how to fix this.

[This document](https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/1RIezQqE4aEhBRmArIAS1mRIZtWFf6JxN_7B4meyWK0Y/pub), outlining the new forms in rc 2, says that for linking to a template reference variable we should use `ngModel` instead of the former `ngForm`. But this doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: The new forms module is not finished. It's to be expected that not everything is yet working as described in that document.

Comment: It is ALMOST working like described in the document. So I was hoping I could get away with that...

Comment: Can you please try adding `name="email"` (with and without `formControlName="email"`)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : Doesn't change anything either way. If I just add name="email" (with and without formControlName="email") then the template reference variable is undefined. When I do the same and add #email="ngModel" or #email="formControlName" I get the same error as described above.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I got this to work for now by additionally importing `import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';` Apparently the directive is missing in the new version and also adding the old one fixes the issue (for now). This is of course just a quick'n'dirty patch.

Comment: I had this as well last week that I got rid of the error by providing `FORM_DIRECTIVES` but in the end it was something else and I could remove it again and didn't get the error back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115128/discussion-between-ole-bjarnstroem-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Sorry, that was while using the old forms.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway! I will open an issue on GitHub and then just wait until new forms support this. This fix is working for now and this is good enough for me when using a release candidate.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It was adressed on Github an will be solved in rc 3. See my reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9363) and it was solved and will be included in RC 3.

Comment: Could you share how your code turned out after updating?

Comment: @tylerjgarland As you can see in the referenced issue the problem wasn't in my code but in Angular RC 2. The fix was included in RC 3. If you're still having this issue I recommend checking out the issue and updating Angular to RC 3 or higher.

Comment: I am running RC4 and still getting the same issue so I hoped you had some insight. Thanks for responding!

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it working. The lack of documentation just slows down the process. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this HTML code:-

```
<form [FormGroup]="adminForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<item>
  <label>EMAIL</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="email" [(ngModel)]="adminForm.email" class="form-control" id="email">
</item>
  <div *ngIf="adminForm.controls.email.hasErrors && adminForm.controls.email.dirty " class="alert alert-danger">
    Enter Valid Email Address!!!
  </div>
</form>
```

TS file:-

```
export class Admin {
    constructor(
            public formBuilder:FormBuilder) //include this Builders
            {
 this.myForm =  new FormGroup({
     'email' : new FormControl( '', Validators.compose([ Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,15})$') ]) )
}) };
```

When you start typing in fields the error message will be displayed!